# Change direction of div class rtl and ltr

Tags: html, css, direction

I have this class , I need to change direction from rtl and ltr how can I do that using css ?

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="services"  >
            <div class="row" >
                @foreach($services as $service)
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="img"><img src="{{$service->get_image->src}}" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <h3><a href="">{{$service->name}}</a></h3>
                        <div class="btns">
                            <a href="{{route('service.details',$service->id)}}" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">{{trans('web.details')}} </a>
                            <a href="{{route('service.form',$service->id)}}" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">{{trans('web.login_service')}} </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Register-transfer-level  is not a tag for right to left....

Comment: Maybe show us how you've tried....

Comment: is this a bootstrap 4 layout ? , if not, update your snippet by removing the <link>

Answer (score 1):

Use the css direction property [w3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_direction.asp)

```
<div style="direaction:rtl;">olleH</div>
```

Or as class name

```
<div class="rtl">olleH</div>
```

And in your stylesheet

```
.rtl{direction:rtl;}
```

Comment: I've already try to use it , but it not worked for me

Answer (score 0):

u can use `direction:ltr` to change the direction, but if the problem for all the pages
u need to change HTML dir

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
```